# How to find if I have a list in a list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to read a list in tcl and then output the elements at each index along with the index.

Ex: mylist = 1 2 {34 45 {567 678}}

my output should be
element at 0 is 1
element at 1 is 2
element at 2 0 is 34
element at 2 1 is 45
element at 2 2 0 is 567
element at 2 2 1 is 678

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't because you can't *in general* tell if `row row row your boat` is a string or a list of five elements. (Tcl does have some internal type information, but it isn't as helpful as you hope.) But if you know the leaves of your nested list structure are all numbers (or anything else that works as a simple bare word), you *can* do it.

```
proc printGuessListStructure {theList {indices {}}} {
    if {$theList eq [lindex $theList 0]} {
        puts "element $theList is at $indices"
        return
    }
    set idx -1
    foreach value $theList {
        printGuessListStructure $value [concat $indices [incr idx]]
    }
}
```

Testing it out:

```
set mylist {1 2 {34 45 {567 678}}}
printGuessListStructure $mylist
```

prints this:

```
element 1 is at 0
element 2 is at 1
element 34 is at 2 0
element 45 is at 2 1
element 567 is at 2 2 0
element 678 is at 2 2 1
```

---

The key is that the test `$theList eq [lindex $theList 0]` is something that holds for simple words, and allows us to avoid recursing forever from the case where a leaf looks like a one-element list.

Also, the reason that looking at Tcl's internal types is unhelpful is that values don't have a fixed type and Tcl's pretty aggressive internally about constant merging. Stuff that you think is a list might be something else temporarily when you look at it. Focusing on what you mean without types avoids confusion better!